# How can I successfully create a two columns layout? One for a vertical navigation bar to the left and the content to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two columns one for a vertical navigation bar to the left and the content column should float right. I tried every method possible. The page did not look good at all. I do not know what I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions? I have been trying for hours but have not been successful. I am still learning the process. I tried floating the Navigation bar left and the content right, but that did not work as desired.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #dce9f7;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 700px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #d9c7b4;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  padding: 25px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.floatleft {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>The Nothing Burger</h1>
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
    <a href="location.html">Location</a>
  </div>
  <h2>Only the best food!</h2>
  <div class="floatright">
    <img src="plate.jpg" alt="Great Food" width="333" height="156">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Fresh, Healthy Cuisine</li>
      <li>Friendly Service</li>
      <li>Open for Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>123 Elm Street<br/> Appleton, CA<br/> 1-888-555-5555
    <br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey did my answer not work for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wrapper div around the navbar element and the content element like shown below and add these styles

```
.wrapperDiv {
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  width: 30%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 70%
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #dce9f7;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 700px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #d9c7b4;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  padding: 25px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.floatleft {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapperDiv {
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  width: 30%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 70%
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>The Nothing Burger</h1>
    <div class="wrapperDiv">
      <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        <a href="location.html">Location</a>
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h2>Only the best food!</h2>
        <div class="floatright">
          <img src="plate.jpg" alt="Great Food" width="333" height="156">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
          <ul>
            <li>Fresh, Healthy Cuisine</li>
            <li>Friendly Service</li>
            <li>Open for Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner</li>
          </ul>
          <div>123 Elm Street<br/> Appleton, CA<br/> 1-888-555-5555
            <br/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes! Flex. Way to go.